# Base64 byte array works on web but not in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, base64

I have a Hex String from a digital sign path and make the conversion to a base64 string.

I can use this in a browser and it display the image with no problem.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,....." />
```

I can save the byte array to a JPG image just fine with:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/userName/Desktop/image3.jpg");
fos.write(bytes);
```

But what I need is to place it into a *JasperReports* which has

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="187" y="69" width="150" height="56" uuid="92404847-27c5-4c2d-b08a-9c0ed0ea562e"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[JRImageLoader.loadImage($P{firma}.getImagen())]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Where the parameter "firma" is a Vo that has a byte [] imagen;

This works for other base64 strings that I've tested but with this it gives me an EOFException while trying to put the image into the report.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : JRImageLoader.loadImage($P{firma}.getImagen())
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:244)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1016)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:492)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:472)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:456)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2057)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
at com.iusacell.surtimiento.action.TestReport.main(TestReport.java:61)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.EOFException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes(JRImageLoader.java:167)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImage(JRImageLoader.java:185)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader$loadImage.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at contratoImagen_1387468965763_87766.evaluate(calculator_contratoImagen_1387468965763_87766:170)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:231)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:339)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.readRLE8(BMPImageReader.java:1362)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.read(BMPImageReader.java:813)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:54)
... 25 more
```

I'm using *JasperReports 5.5.0* library, *JDK 1.6*.
The string is:

```
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
```

Comment: What is declaration of `$P{firma}`? Did you add import to *jrxml* file?

Comment: Yes, the import is from my Vo <parameter name="firma" class="xx.xx.xx.xx.ImagenVo"/>

It works just fine with other base64 strings, but not with the ones the signature pad gives me